# Fixed dimensions for the "Questions that may already have your answer" box?

Tags: bug

When you're asking a new question, is it at all possible to place a fixed size on the "Questions that may already have your answer" region between your question title and the question body?

As I am moving between input fields, that box auto-reloads which causes its contents to be cleared while it searches for new results.  During this time, the box collapses, only to expand back to its usual fixed size.  This causes the page to herkyjerk up and down as the box expands and collapses which sometimes causes me to click something I didn't want to click.